# Android set edittext values into multiple textviews

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext, android-toast

I want to set text of `edittext` into multiple `textviews` like if i enter `'HELLO'`, then H will be set to a textview, E to another.

I have written below code where text is showing one by one on Toast message.

App crashes if i use `textview.settext()`;

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String s=editText.getText().toString();

            char charArray[] = s.toCharArray();


            for(int i=0;i<charArray.length;i++){

                char r=charArray[i];

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+r, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }   

        }
    });
```

Comment: What error do you get? is that index outOfBound?

Comment: Post your logcat error with some more relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should do something like the following :

```
ArrayList<TextView> tvList = new ArrayList<TextView>(); 
        String str = "hello"; 
        for(int i=0 ;i<tvList.size() ; i++){
            tvList.get(i).setText(str.charAt(i)+"");
        }
```

what you should be doing is saving your textviews in a list , then do as i menthoind .

Hope that helps .

Comment: this cause `Resource Not Found Exception` because you can't set `char` to `TextView`, you must cast to String then set to `TextView`

Comment: I don't ask this question.

Comment: oh sorry i thought u r the one who asked the question .

Comment: This code will set letter `h` to every TextView in the ArrayList, which is not what OP wants.